# Polynomial and polynomial functions

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the difference between polynomial and polynomial functions? Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two polynomials, are there cases when $f\neq g$ but $f^\sim = g^\sim$, where $f^\sim$ and $g^\sim$ are the polynomial functions of $f$ and $g$ respectively? Are there cases when $f= g$ but $f^\sim \neq g^\sim$? When are $f=g$ and when are $f^\sim = g^\sim$?

How do you prove that $(fg)^\sim (t) = f^\sim (t) g^\sim (t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a polynomial $p(x)$, the $x$ is a placeholder. That is, all that matters for polynomials are the positions of the coefficients and the rules to add and multiply polynomials.

A polynomial function is precisely that, a function, that evaluates over some ring.

The two notions do agree on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, but they do not over other fields.

As an example, let $K=\mathbb Z_3$. Consider the polynomials $p,q\in K[x]$, where 
$$
p(x)=1+x^2,\ \ q(x)=1+x^4.
$$
Then of course $p,q$ are different as polynomials. But they are equal as functions:
$$
p^\sim(0)=1=q^\sim(0),\ \ p^\sim(1)=2=q^\sim(2),\ \ p^\sim(2)=2=q^\sim(2),\ \ 
$$
so $p^\sim=q^\sim$.

For your last equality, note that the left-hand-side consists of doing the formal product of $f$ and $g$ and then replacing $x$ with $t$. While the right-hand-side consists of replacing $x$ with $t$ and then doing the formal product. It should be clear that both things achieve the same. Just writing $f$ and $g$ in terms of their coefficients and power of $x$ and writing both sides should make it apparent that they are equal.

Comment: Are there cases when the polynomial functions are equal but the polynomials are not equal? Also, are there any non-trivial rings over which they do not agree? (The integer modulo ring seems a bit arbitrary and like black magic to me :) )

Comment: That's exactly what I'm showing you: an example where the polynomial functions are equal even though the polynomials are not equal. Not sure what you mean by "non-trivial" ring.

Comment: Opps wait I meant are there cases when the polynomial functions are not equal but the polynomials are equal? Also, by non-trivial ring, I don't mean rings that are non-zero. I meant rings that have infinite elements.

Comment: If the polynomials are equal, then they are the same, and so the corresponding polynomial functions are the same. As for infinite rings, you can make the same example work on an infinite ring by considering an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z_3$, i.e.  $$ R=\{(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}:\ z_n\in\mathbb Z_3\ \forall n\in\mathbb N\} $$ with pointwise operations.